# How can I change the direction of overflow/wrap on small screens for a single bootstrap column?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, drupal-8

I have a bootstrap row with two columns on large screens (`Text 2` and `Image 2`, below), which wraps on small screens so `Text 2` is on top and `Image 2` is on bottom, as expected by default. On small screens, I would like `Image 2` to be on top and `Text 2` to be on bottom instead, but only for this row, not my entire page. In other words, I would like that single row to wrap right to left rather than left to right.

```
Large Screen:
Image 1         Text 1
Text 2          Image 2
Image 3         Text 3 

Small Screen:
Image 1
Text 1
**Text 2
Image 2**
Image 3
Text 3

Desired Small Screen:
Image 1
Text 1
**Image 2
Text 2**
Image 3
Text 3
```

How can I change the direction bootstrap wraps this row?

Comment: Post the code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap 4 comes with a class to handle this - `order-[1-12]`

It works on the same breakpoints `[sm / md / lg / xl]` as everything else, so you should be familiar with how to set it up - But, to get what you want, would go something like this

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container mt-4">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 order-sm-1 col-md-6">
      <div class="card card-body">Image 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12  order-sm-2 col-md-6">
      <div class="card card-body">Text 1</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-12 order-sm-4 col-md-6 order-md-3">
      <div class="card card-body">Text 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 order-sm-3 col-md-6 order-md-4">
      <div class="card card-body">Image 2</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-12 order-sm-5 col-md-6">
      <div class="card card-body">Image 3 </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 order-sm-6 col-md-6">
      <div class="card card-body">Text 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks! I was expecting a class that would simply reverse the order, not this much more granular item-level control.